# getGroupList method of activiti returns only 10 groups from it's rest service though I have 16 groups in database

Tags: activiti

getGroupList method of activiti returns only 10 groups from it's rest service though I have 16 groups in database.
Here is the respone for getGroupList of activiti.

{"data":
[{"id":"BASE","url":"://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/identity/groups/BASE","name":"BASE","type":"assignment"},
 {"id":"HEALTH_SAFETY","url":"://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/identity/groups/HEALTH_SAFETY","name":"Health and Safety","type":"assignment"},
 {"id":"NEGOTIATOR","url":"://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/identity/groups/NEGOTIATOR","name":"Negotiator","type":"assignment"},
 {"id":"RADIO_PLANNING","url":"://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/identity/groups/RADIO_PLANNING","name":"Radio Planning","type":"assignment"},
 {"id":"SITE_ACQUISITION","url":"://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/identity/groups/SITE_ACQUISITION","name":"Site Acquisition Coordinator","type":"assignment"},
 {"id":"SPARK_BPC","url":"://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/identity/groups/SPARK_BPC","name":"Building Permit Coordinator","type":"assignment"},
 {"id":"SPARK_PM","url":"://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/identity/groups/SPARK_PM","name":"SPARK PM","type":"assignment"},
 {"id":"SPARK_PMO","url":"://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/identity/groups/SPARK_PMO","name":"SPARK PMO","type":"assignment"},
 {"id":"SPARK_SE","url":"://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/identity/groups/SPARK_SE","name":"SPARK Site Engineer","type":"assignment"},
 {"id":"admin","url":"://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/identity/groups/admin","name":"Admin","type":"security-role"}],
"total":16,
"start":0,
"sort":"id",
"order":"asc",
"size":10}

Comment: "total":16, "start":0, "sort":"id", "order":"asc", "size":10          It's 16 in total but size specifies 10. How can I get all 16 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default list size for all Activiti Rest calls is 10. If you need more, then use the "size" query parameter in the URl.